# How to select columns through VBA when the columns selectin reference is: A,E,D,S

Tags: excel, vba

I'm requesting a parameter from the user to specify columns (in Excel) to select, but am having some issues with converting the value to a string that I can use in VBA for reference.

I'm trying to avoid having the user enter A:A,E:E,D:D,S:S and instead just enter A,E,D,S in a cell.  I'm sure the answer is right there but at the moment it's escaping me.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried - please post your code?

Comment: Well, I've tried using different properties but that's about it:  'Columns(1,5,4,19).select'

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post what you've tried than if you just ask people to write the code for you from scratch.

Comment: Split the string on `,` then iterate through the resulting array.

Comment: Sorry, got "Enter" happy on my keyboard and didn't send what I've tried:  I've tried using different properties like Columns(1,5,4,19).select or Column("A,E,D,S").select or Range("A,E,D,S").select and Array("1","5","4","19").select.  I get an error on all of them.  Something tells me that there has to be a way with one of those to accomplish what I'm looking for.  I'm thinking maybe I just have a syntax issue.  If not, I'm going to have to figure out how to write some routine to convert that value to a reference I can use.  I really don't want to do that though.

Comment: What are you going to do with these columns once you have selected them?  (There's usually not much point in using the `Select` method, so you may be better off not even trying.)

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to create a quick csv button that will prompt the user for the columns they want to save out in to a csv file.  Then my code will save out the file to a csv with only the columns specified.  Maybe I shouldn't have used 'Select' as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said,

Split on the `,` and iterate through the resultant array and build the range:

```
Sub fooooo()
Dim str As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim strArr() As String

str = "A,E,D,S" 'you can change this to the cell reference you want.

strArr = Split(str, ",")
With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change to your sheet
    Set rng = .Range(strArr(0) & ":" & strArr(0))
    For i = 1 To UBound(strArr)
        Set rng = Union(rng, .Range(strArr(i) & ":" & strArr(i)))
    Next i
End With

Debug.Print rng.Address

End Sub
```

---

You can always turn this into a Function that returns a range:

```
Function fooooo(str As String, ws As Worksheet) As Range

Dim rng As Range
Dim strArr() As String



strArr = Split(str, ",")
With ws ' change to your sheet
    Set rng = .Range(strArr(0) & ":" & strArr(0))
    For i = 1 To UBound(strArr)
        Set rng = Union(rng, .Range(strArr(i) & ":" & strArr(i)))
    Next i
End With

Set fooooo = rng

End Function
```

Then you would call it like this from any sub you need:

```
Sub foofind()
Dim rng As Range
Dim str As String

str = "A,E,D,S"

Set rng = fooooo(str, Worksheets("Sheet1"))

Debug.Print rng.Address
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for the suggestion.  I completely missed your initial post, apologies.  Unfortunately, I was actually trying to avoid having to write a routine to accomplish this but it sounds like there's no magic bullet for what I'm trying to do.  Thank you.  I'll give this a shot.

Comment: @JonRose this is very quick. As you are parsing a memory array the loop will be nearly instantaneous.

Comment: This works.  Thanks for the quick response.  Now I just have to disect it to to figure out how it works.  I'm not familiar with working with Array's in VBA so this should add some value for later use as well.  Thanks again.